Retrieve Data extensions in Salesforce marketing cloud
I was wondering if there's any way to get all the data extention available in different BUs with created date and last modified data - so I can delete those which are not in use.
Is there any way anyone can suggest so I dont need to go 1 by 1 to see there last modified date and delete them.

Yes.
You can use the code below in parent BU; it will QueryAllAccounts.
Add more fields like lastModifiedDate etc. to var cols and add them to the output object under result.push({...
The retrievable fields in a DE are described in the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

try {
    var cols = ["Name", "CustomerKey", "CategoryID","Client.ID"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "CustomerKey",
        SimpleOperator: "isNotNull",
        Value: ""
    };
    var opts = {
        BatchSize: 2500
    };
    var props = {
        QueryAllAccounts: true
    };

    var result = [];
    var moreData = true;
    var reqID = null;

    Write("<script>\n");
    Write("console.log('Starting Data Extension retrieval');\n");

    while (moreData) {
        if (reqID) props.ContinueRequest = reqID;

        var req = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter, opts, props);

        Write("console.log('API Response for Data Extensions:', " + Stringify(req) + ");\n");

        if (req && req.Status && (req.Status === 'OK' || req.Status === 'MoreDataAvailable')) {
            moreData = req.HasMoreRows;
            reqID = req.RequestID;
            
            if (req.Results && req.Results.length > 0) {
                Write("console.log('Retrieved " + req.Results.length + " Data Extensions');\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < req.Results.length; i++) {
                    var de = req.Results[i];
                    if (de.Name.indexOf("_") !== 0) {  // Exclude system Data Extensions
                        result.push({
                            id: de.CustomerKey
                            ,text: de.Name + ' (' + de.CustomerKey + ')'
                            ,customerKey: de.CustomerKey
                            ,name: de.Name
                            ,accountId: de.Client.ID
                        });
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Write("console.log('No Data Extensions found in this batch');\n");
            }
        } else {
            Write("console.log('Error in API call:', " + Stringify(req) + ");\n");
            moreData = false;
        }
    }

    Write("console.log('Total Data Extensions processed: " + result.length + "');\n");
    Write("var dataExtensions = " + Stringify(result) + ";\n");
    Write("console.log('Data Extensions variable set');\n");
    Write("<\/script>\n");

} catch(error) {
    Write("<script>console.error('Error: " + Stringify(error) + "');<\/script>");
}
</script>


Hi @jonas
I have ran the above script to capture all DEs in my targeted DE, it ran successfully- but the data didn;t captured in my targeted DE. I dont know whats going wrong.
I also try to run the for specific BU but the script ran but its not capturing the logs in tageted DE

the code in my answer is not writing to any DE; all it does is create an array of objects and print to a cloudpage. so if you used the code as-is, the behavior you observed is to be expected; if you wrote the insertion code yourself, we cannot help as we don't know what you did. What you need to do is add a line of "Platform.Function.UpsertData()directly over or under theresult.push({` part. You can likely find a working example on this site.

Right, If I need to extract all the DE from a specific BU and put the data in the targeted DE, what do I need to do- you help will be appreciated.
Thank you
